# Bookshelf.js-nested withRelated() (equivalent of multiple inner joins)

Tags: bookshelf.js

I'm new to using Bookshelf and am trying to figure out how to do the equivalent of multiple joins. I guess that this is doable with withRelated, somehow? I understand that I can do several queries with each other's results, but it seems hacky.

Specifically, I've got several tables: User, Organization, Endpoint and Setting.

I would like, given a username, to return a list of endpoints with all their columns, with their associated settings and all their columns, and their associated organization's name.

Is there a good way to do this with Bookshelf? I'm seeing this [Bookshelf EZ Fetch plugin](https://github.com/DJAndries/bookshelf-ez-fetch) that seems built for such use cases, but would like to know the 
"native" syntax, as it were.

Here are my models:

User:

```
'use strict';

const bookshelf = require('../config/bookshelf_instance');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const bcrypt = Promise.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt'));
const Role = require('./role');
const securityConfig = require('../config/security_config');
const Organization = require('./organization');

module.exports = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'user',
    roles() {
        return this.belongsToMany(Role, 'map_user_role');
    },
    validPassword(password) {
        return bcrypt.compareAsync(password, this.attributes.password);
    },
    organization(){
        return this.hasOne(Organization, 'organization_id');
    },
    initialize() {
        this.on('saving', model => {
            if (!model.hasChanged('password')) return;

            return Promise.coroutine(function* () {
                const salt = yield bcrypt.genSaltAsync(securityConfig.saltRounds);
                const hashedPassword = yield bcrypt.hashAsync(model.attributes.password, salt);
                model.set('password', hashedPassword);
            })();
        });
    }
});
```

Organization:

```
'use strict';

const bookshelf = require('../config/bookshelf_instance');
const Endpoint = require('./endpoint');
const User = require('./user');
const Group = require('./endpoint_group');

module.exports = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'organization',
    endpoints() {
        return this.hasMany(Endpoint, 'organization_id');
    },
    users() {
        return this.hasMany(User, 'organization_id');
    },
    groups() {
        return this.hasMany(Group, 'organization_id');
    }
});
```

Endpoint:

```
'use strict';

const bookshelf = require('../config/bookshelf_instance');
const ezFetch = require('bookshelf-ez-fetch');
const Organization = require('./organization');
const Settings = require('./endpoint_settings');
const Group = require('./endpoint_group');

bookshelf.plugin(ezFetch());

module.exports = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'endpoint',
    organization() {
        return this.hasOne(Organization, 'organization_id');
    },
    settings() {
        return this.hasOne(Settings, 'settingsId')
    },
    group() {
        return this.belongsToMany(Group, 'parentGroupIds')
    }
});
```

Setting:

```
'use strict';

const bookshelf = require('../config/bookshelf_instance');
const Endpoint = require('./endpoint');

module.exports = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'endpoint_setting',
    endpoint() {
        return this.hasOne(Endpoint, 'endpoint_settings_id')
    }
});
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to share your model definitions so everybody can see the relations between them instead of having to deduce them from your description.

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly, I think you can use `.` in `withRelated` to fetch nested relations. You may want to refer this https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/issues/496

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is having this problem, I was told by a colleague that ORMs are usually not good at this sort of thing. I ended up just making a chain of queries.

Comment: It depends on the number of rows you're retrieving and the number of users requesting it. But if organizations do not have a lot of endpoints, and each endpoints do not have a lot of settings, and no hard traffic, you can go easily by chaining relations with dots like `.fetchAll({ withRelated: ['organization.endpoints.settings', 'organization.groups'])` that will for each user, load organization, and load all endpoints of organization, and load all settings on each endpoint. Will also load all groups for organization. But if data is huge enough, better go with direct sql or query builder.